# Как вшить ссылку в диплинк facebook

Tags: java, android-studio

Суть дела такова:
В апу вместе с диплинком мне нужно прокинуть ссылку с возможностью замены урла в любое время. Я реализовал это через cloud firestore. Но очень заморочно. Есть ещё варианты? Branch и т.д. не подойдёт. Дип нужен именно фбшный